# How can I blur an entire video using iMovie or similar?

Tags: imovie

I've been searching for this and could not find a single solution.

How can I apply a blur effect to an entire video? not just specific objects or faces.

Answer (score 1):

I work with a company that makes a product called Wondershare Video Editor for mac.  It is what I personally use so i can only offer my solution by this software. Check the screenshot first:
[image]
In a word, you can make it by the mosaic function in this software. Now i will show you step by step (8 steps in total).

1. Step one, import the video file and drag and drop to the video
   timeline
2. Step two, click the power tool button to open the editing window
3. Step three, choose Mosaic function
4. Step four, pick up "Apply Mosaic to the clip"
5. Step five, click "Add"
6. Step six, adjust the size of blur area you need, if you want to blur
   the whole video, drag the rectangular to the border
7. Step seven, you can change the heavy of this blur by dragging the
   percent button
8. Last step, click "OK"

Done! Check the preview video screenshot as follow:[image]
Export it, you will get a blur video. I wish it's helpful for you.

Comment: Please remember to disclose your affiliation with Wondershare when posting an answer about it.  It is fine to post about Wondershare in situations where it is a relevant and helpful answer and this is otherwise a good post, but disclosing your affiliation on the answer is necessary or they will end up being deleted in the future.)  I have updated this answer with an example of how you can work the affiliation in to the answer.

Comment: Thanks AJ Henderson, i will pay attention to it next time and won't only recommend the products from that company and will try my best to solve many other questions!